# Using GTK+ And Xcode4

Tags: c, xcode, macos, gtk

So I've installed GTK-OSX from http://gtk-osx.sourceforge.net/
I've added my /location-to-GTK/lib directory to Xcode's header search path. But exactly which library files do I add to my Xcode project? There are about ~100 of them and I don't think need to add all of them.

Can anyone with GTK-OSX experience assist me?

Comment: Noone can point me in the right direction with gtk and xcode?